# Why I am getting typeError value is null but In my firebug I can see that there is the values and not null?

Tags: php, json, jquery

Why I am getting typeError value is null but In my firebug I can that there is the values and not null, Whats the problem?

Here's my ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'get-products.php',
    type: 'post',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: { category: $('.category').val().trim(), keyword: $('.keyword').val().trim() },
    success: function(data){
        var toAppend = '';
        toAppend += '<thead><th>Product Name</th><th>Image</th><th>Price</th><th>Weight</th><th>ASIN</th><th>Category</th></thead>';
        if(typeof data === "object"){
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                toAppend += '<tr><td>'+
                data[i]['product_name'][0]+'</td><td><img src="'+
                data[i]['image'][0]+'" alt=""></td><td>'+
                data[i]['price'][0]+'</td><td>'+                            
                data[i]['weight']+'</td><td>'+                                      
                data[i]['asin'][0]+'</td><td>'+                                         
                data[i]['category'][0]+'</td></tr>';
            }
            $('.data-results').append(toAppend);
        }
    }
});
```

Here's my php code I know this is working:

```
    foreach($xml->Items->Item as $item){
$items_from_amazon[] = array(
        'asin'=>$item->ASIN,
        'product_name'=>$item->ItemAttributes->Title, 
        'image'=>$item->SmallImage->URL,
        'price'=>$item->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormattedPrice, 
        'category'=>$item->ItemAttributes->ProductGroup, 
        'weight' => (string) $item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight.' lbs');
}
echo json_encode($items_from_amazon);
?>
```

Here's the result from my firebug:

[image]

Here's my sample ouput, can I still display the result even do there is still null result like in image if the image is null then there is no image displayed

[image]

Comment: see 7th element in firebug, image is null there

Comment: _Sidenote_ You have missed a `+` > `data[i]['weight']+'</td><td>'`

Comment: @undefined, there is + in my real code, my mistake soryy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the firebug image it looks like it says  image is null at the 7th index. 
So if you do data.image[index] You are accessing a memory location that is invalid. The image property must point to something.

```
             for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
//You can save default image in a global variable, hidden div... it is up to you. 
                var img ;
                if(data[i]['image'] === null){
                  img = defaultImage ;
                }
                else
                { 
                    img = data[i]['image'][0];  
                }
                toAppend += '<tr><td>'+
                data[i]['product_name'][0]+'</td><td><img src="'+
                img +'" alt=""></td><td>'+ //use img here
                data[i]['price'][0]+'</td><td>'+                            
                data[i]['weight']+'</td><td>'+                                      
                data[i]['asin'][0]+'</td><td>'+                                         
                data[i]['category'][0]+'</td></tr>';
            }
```

You hopefully get the idea.

Comment: How can I still display the result?

Comment: I would debug your server side code to see why an element is missing an image. There isn't much info in the code you gave us.

Comment: actually I am fetching data from AMazon using AWS API and I cannot prevent that something the data is null, CAn i still display the result?

Comment: Add an if statement to see if it points to null. If it does.. `continue`

Comment: I have added Screenshot on my question, now I want to know for example if image is null it can still display the other data?

Comment: I believe you can. You can make a custom "No Image" image. And use that if image is null.

Comment: is this a good way of checking the data if null? if(data[i]['image'][0] == null) ?

Comment: No.. `if(data[i]['image'] == null)` Do this before you string your html code together. I will edit my answer.

Comment: can i still use this in other data? just to be sure?

Comment: Use what, the image? I have to get to class.. I will reply when I get back. Gl.